# How to redirect to referenced entity form with Rules

Tags: commerce, rules, entities

I use drupal commerce. I have several entityform type. Each product has entity reference to one of these forms. How to page redirect to referenced form url when a product added to cart.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use Rules for this. It should already be installed since Drupal Commerce requires it.

Create a new rule by going to Admin > Config > Workflow > Rules, and click Add rule.

A rule consists of 3 parts.

### The event, the action that triggers the rule.

The event that initiates the rule would be `After adding a product to the cart`.

### The conditions, the checks to make sure the rule applies.

Use this to find your reference field;

Add a rule `entity had field` and check if the `commerce_line_item` (I suppose you get that by default) has a field `commerce_product`. Then add a second check to see if `commerce_line_item:commerce_product` has a field `entity_reference`.

Depending on where you created the field you might require several layers.

### The actions, what to do if the rule is valid.

You want to use the `Page redirect` action in the `system` group. Make sure to click the `data selector` button, then you can search the redirect path. It suppose should look something like `commerce_line_item:commerce_product:field_reference:url`.

Comment: Hi. `[commerce-product:field_reference]` gets the form name as url but `[commerce-product:field_reference:url]` doesn't get the form url. Page redirected to front page

Comment: The names are different as per you installation. Use the `data selection` widget (the auto fill input) to find the exact names. If the first provides a url, use it to do the redirect.

Comment: data selector does not provide `:url`. I can enter only with direct input. May  `:url` token unsupperted for entity form  via  entity reference? Forms url data looks like this: `"weight" : "0",
  "paths" : { "submit" : {
      "source" : "eform\/submit\/form-3",
      "alias" : "the_url_i_need",
      "language" : "und"
    }
  }`

Comment: can you get the id of the entity form? You might need to use an action to `load the entity by id` first. Perhaps the url will become available then. Order does matter, so make sure this action is performed first. If the data selector does not have it, it does not exist.

Comment: `[commerce-product:field_reference:id]` works without `load the entity by id` but `[commerce-product:field_reference:url]` doesnt work with or without `load the entity by id` and still url token not provided by data selector.

Comment: I tried with a node and just tried again. Added an entity reference field, referenced an entityform (form and submission). Then in rules checked if the node had the field and added the redirect action. The url token was there for both forms and submissions. I am sorry there is nothing more I can do. It should have worked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33388/discussion-between-mtin-nong-and-neograph734).

Comment: Sorry for not responding in chat. I ran the newer version RC2 of entityform. That might be the cause.

Comment: And it appears RC2 was only tagged on git, but not available for download. Try the lastest dev version, that should work too.